# Generics range over union of maps

Tags: go, generics

There is a simple example of use of generics in which we want to copy a map

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myMap interface {
    map[string]int | map[string]float64
}

func copyMap[T myMap](m T) T {
    newMap := make(T)
    for key, elem := range m {
        newMap[key] = elem
    }

    return newMap
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{"seven": 7}
    fmt.Println(copyMap(m))
}
```

demo [here](https://go.dev/play/p/6-KCM2M4g4e)

This code fails to compile returning error

```
./prog.go:12:17: invalid argument: cannot make T: no core type
./prog.go:13:25: cannot range over m (variable of type T constrained by myMap) (T has no core type)
./prog.go:14:18: invalid operation: cannot index m (variable of type T constrained by myMap)
```

How can I circumvent this issue and have a working generic copyMap function working for types `map[string]int` and `map[string]float64`?

Comment: Are you aware of [`maps.Clone`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Clone)?

Comment: Nope I was not aware of this function. I've answered my question and added your comment into the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
func copyMap[T ~map[string]V, V any](m T) T {/* ... */}
```

[demo](https://go.dev/play/p/AwvDGkcAoEK)

---

Or indeed just use https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/062eb4c6:maps/maps.go;l=65 (who uses a similar construct) as @jubObs mentioned.